# 1D convolutional neural network weight matrix

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'am building 1D CNN in Keras in order to classify short pulses in analog signal.
my model is as follows:

```
    def one_dim_cnn_cust_model(n_kernel_1, n_kernel_2, n_outputs):
    
      input_shape = [1, 25]
      model = Sequential()
      model.add(Reshape((25, 1), input_shape=(input_shape)))
    
      model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=n_kernel_1, activation='relu', 
      input_shape=input_shape[1:]))
      model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
      model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=n_kernel_2, activation='relu',padding="same"))
      model.add(Dropout(0.5))
      model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=10))#35
    
      model.add(Flatten())
    
      model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
      model.add(Dropout(0.5))
      model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
      model.add(Dropout(0.5))
      model.add(Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid'))
      print(model.output_shape)
      return (model)
```

```
    n_kernel_1 =16,
    n_kernel_2 =16,
    n_outputs = 2.
```

[image: model summry is :]

After training, i want to extract the features ,weights and biases to be able to implement this simple CNN in C++. to make sure i understand it , I've implemented ,the first convolutional layer as follow:

```
    l1_outouts_calc = np.zeros((8,10))
    kernel_size=16
    for ch in range (0,8):
        for stride in range(0, 10):
            data_section = input_vect[0, stride:stride + kernel_size]
            cnv_plus_bias = np.sum(data_section * l1_weights[ch]) + l1_bias[ch]
            l1_outouts_calc[ch,stride]=(np.max([0,cnv_plus_bias[0]]))#Relu activation
    l1_outouts_calc=l1_outouts_calc.T
```

I got the same results as Keras.
weight matrix dimensions : 8x16 (numpy array).

Then i've implemented the secound layer , which is fully connected.
weight matrix dimension :  8x16 (numpy array).

```
    fc_outouts_calc = np.dot(l1_outouts_calc,fc_weights) + fc_bias
    fc_outouts_calc = np.maximum(fc_outouts_calc, 0)
```

Again , i got the same results as Keras
Then i got misunderstanding while try to implement the third layer which is convolutional layer , after the fully connected layer.
I got weight matrix dimension of 16x16x8 and i dont understand how to implement this layer in Python using Numpy.

As far as i know , 1D convolution with 2D kernel and stride constriant , should be implemented as follows:
(based on the dimension i got)

```
    l3_outouts_calc = np.zeros((8, 10))
    kernel_size=16
    for weight_ch in range(0, 8):
        for stride in range(0, 10):
            sum_val = 0.0
            for din_ch in range(0, 16):
                data_section = fc_outouts_pad[din_ch, stride:stride + kernel_size]
                cnv_plus_bias = np.sum(data_section * l3_weights[weight_ch,din_ch, :])+l3_bias[weight_ch]
                                
                sum_val += np.max([0,cnv_plus_bias ]) 
            l3_outouts_calc[weight_ch, stride] = sum_val
```

its simply mean to loop step by step over the strides,for each stride extract the compatible section from data in ,compute the convolution for each section with its compatible kernel ,then sum.
But i dont understand why i got weight matrix of 16 channels of 16x8 matrices, and how can i implement it using Numpy.

Thank you and hope you can reply a short explenation.

Comment: You said that you got the same dimensions as Keras after first conv, but you got 8x16 and the summary shows 10x8. How is it so?

Comment: Weight matrix dimension is 8x16 m the output is 8X10 due to the stride

Comment: As i understood i need to calculate matrix multiplication for the output of the FC layer( which is dimension is 10x16) with each channel in the weight 3D matrix ( which its dimension is 16x8)  ,then sum the 16 output matrices( the third dimension of the weight matrix is 16)  over axis 0. the question is when do i need to add the bias and perform Relu? do i need to do this 2 operation vector by vector?